# What does the format means in fits.Column()?

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I'm learning to create a fits file and I looked up in the astropy coumentation: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/
But I dud not understand what do `format='20A'` and `'E'` mean. And what does changing them imply to my fits file? The answer doesn't seem to be anywhere in the astropy documentation.

That is the code from the documentation tutorial:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits

a1 = np.array(['NGC1001', 'NGC1002', 'NGC1003'])
a2 = np.array([11.1, 12.3, 15.2])
col1 = fits.Column(name='target', format='20A', array=a1)
col2 = fits.Column(name='V_mag', format='E', array=a2)

cols = fits.ColDefs([col1, col2])

hdu = fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(cols)

hdu.writeto('table3.fits')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in the documentation [here](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/usage/table.html#column-creation). However, these are low-level details of the FITS format. If you're not already deeply familiar with FITS and just want to make a table, using the higher-level [`Table`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/usage/table.html#column-creation)

For example the same table could be created like:

```
>>> from astropy.table import Table
>>>  t = Table({
...     'target': np.array([b'NGC1001', b'NGC1002', b'NGC1003'], dtype='S20'),
...     np.array([11.1, 12.3, 15.2])
...})
```

Now you have a table represtation that's not at all specific to FITS, but you can write it to a FITS file like:

```
>>> t.write('table.fits', format='fits')
```

And the result will be roughly the same. It will handle converting the dtypes to the appropriate FITS column types. It's usually only necessary to use the low-level library if you need fine-grained control over the exact format of the FITS file, but your mileage may vary.

BTW when making a table the way you did, it has been unnecessary for a long time in most cases to explicitly make a `ColDefs` object. You can just pass a plain list of columns to `BinTableHDU.from_columns` like `BinTableHDU.from_columns([col1, col2])`. The fact that the `ColDefs` class is exposed to users at all is mostly a legacy case, or for some very special purposes. The docs might do a better job of emphasizing that it's not important.